# How to display a DIVs content in another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible do display the content of one `div` in another? For example: I want to make a main `div` that will hold some content, for example text and a picture. Next to this there will be a smaller `div` that shows a preview of the main `div` (like a thumbnail).

No server-side languages allowed :/ Only html/css and JavaScript libaries.

Comment: What do you mean by "preview"? All of the same content but somehow zoomed to fit your smaller div, or all of the same content with a scrollbar, or an extract of just the top bit, or...?

Comment: yes,all the same content but smaller, like in google docs presentation tool, or power point.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery plugin [**jquery.fracs**](http://larsjung.de/fracs/) uses `<canvas>` to display an outline of the document. I've not used it myself, but you might be able to customise it to suit your needs. The previous link uses it to display the document outline on the right. There is also a more in-depth [demo](http://larsjung.de/fracs/demo/) showing the internal calculations.

Comment: any idea how can I use it ? I am building a presentation tool in html/css/js only, that`s why I need a "preview" feature.

Comment: The first link in my answer has pretty good documentation but you will need jQuery and the fracs plugin. Aside from the docs, I have never tried setting it up, so sorry I can't help further. You could maybe try contacting the author directly?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for you with your restrictions, in my opinion would be the use of an iframe. There are variable debates and issues like cross-browser but you can google all about it. IMO IE is dead anyway...

I would suggest AJAX, but you said you can't do that.

Here is some BASIC code to get your started.

```
<iframe src="blank.html" height="100" width="200">Error Msg for not capable</iframe>
```

OR

Create a special div to hold this "preview content box" and use CSS to get it just perfect.
Now you could do:

```
<iframe src="blank.html" height="100%" width="100%">Error Msg for not capable</iframe>
```

Hope this helps you!